# IIS error The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have the following setup:

1. windows server 2012
2. visual developer 2012
3. IIS 7.
   I have changed the authentication type on my web config file from form to windows as follow:-

But when I try to access the ASP.NET MVC site the got the following error:-

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Access is denied. 
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

What could be the problem?

Comment: can we see the `<authentication>` section of the web.config

Comment: <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

Comment: and i have disabled the anonymouse authentication,asp.net impersonation + form authitication. And i have enabled the windows authitication under the IIS authentication section

Comment: have restarted the server and now it is working fine, but i am having the folloiwng problem is that "the user will be promted to enter his username and password when he tries to access the application", so why did not the asp.net mvc automatically sign the user in according  to his windows username and password.

THanks

Comment: replace these in your web.config file  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Answer (score 13):

Please change the Web.config file

From

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

To

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>    
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>    
</system.web>
```

Also Web.config for 2 users

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="DOMAIN_NAME\my_name,DOMAIN_NAME\USER_NAME" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: Is <deny users="*" /> in the last section a valid one? It is allowing 2 but denying all?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by installing the windows authentication feature of server 2012.
Jump into control panel/programs/ add windows features. Go to the features section, expand Web server (IIS)/Web server/Security and install 'Windows Authentication'
Recycle your application pool or iisreset for it to take effect

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you can also left-click on the project in **Solution Explorer** and change the **Windows Authentication** property to **Enabled** in the Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I have following configuration in web config.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

and on login failure i am redirecting to one page. but on click of any button in the redirected page i was getting this error.

I tried the above answer of @jaydeep and it worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39092914/6665971

Now for all other pages it will not authorized and for specific page i am able to redirect using `server.transfer` function.